# restricción de elementos con readdir

Tags: php

Necesito saber si es posible restringir la apertura de archivos con readdir. Me baso en el ejemplo que aparece en:
http://desarrollo-geek.blogspot.cl/2012/05/mostrar-imagen-desde-directorio-con-php.html
Supongamos que en una carpeta tengo varios archivos jpg numerados llamados img-preview, y también en la misma carpeta tengo otros archivos jpg numerados llamados img-gallery. Es posible, basado en el ejemplo del sitio, abrir solo los archivos img-preview.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el comando glob [Manual Oficial](http://php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php).

Un ejemplo de uso es

```
<?php
// Recorrer todos los ficheros *.php del directorio ext/spl/examples/
// y mostrar sus nombres y tamaños
$it = new DirectoryIterator("glob://ext/spl/examples/*.php");
foreach($it as $f) {
    printf("%s: %.1FK\n", $f->getFilename(), $f->getSize()/1024);
}
?>
```

Comment: He hecho varios intentos pero no he podido concretar (http://ideone.com/oujhQ8). Parto con un par de códigos base para desarrollar; uno con la función readdir (http://ideone.com/dcwMn7) y otro con la clase dir (http://ideone.com/zLa5OE).

Comment: Ahora sí. http://ideone.com/k2jNjf